# Where to find information on Designing Trending Content?

Tags: graphs

I'm currently working on a design project for a product's 'Trending' feature. Currently we have a Q&A Forum that will display small rating stars next to each topic.

We are looking into ways to leverage this/redesign this and use it in other areas of the product. The other areas could be the user profile area, Ideas, Search Results...etc.

Beyond the typical Google search research that I am performing, I wonder if anyone has any good blog posts, books, etc.. that they could recommend.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few useful links from some great pattern websites

---

**http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/RateContent**

### https://www.pinterest.com/eyalrofe/ui-patterns-rating/

Other few more links but not that good as above two links

http://zurb.com/patterntap/pattern/get-satisfaction-emotional-rating-system-getsatisfaction

http://zurb.com/patterntap/pattern/large-heart-rating-form-fflick

http://ui-patterns.com/users/6904/collections/ratings_1/screenshots/12189

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it really helped me out! (Forgot about UI Patterns.com)

Comment: Always give one up vote if you like my answer, Glad it really helped you